# Suggestions for this integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Any ideas on how to approach this problem are welcome.
$$ \int \sqrt{\frac{x}{(x+2a)((x-a)^2+3b^2)}} dx\;,$$
where
$$ a = -\frac{1}{12}c+\frac{1}{c}$$
and 
$$ b = \frac{1}{12}c+\frac{1}{c}$$

Comment: Maple gives an answer in terms of elliptic functions.  Unlikely that you are going to get anything simple.

Comment: yeah I know. Thats why I posted here, for new ideas.

Comment: Good luck.  But IMHO unlikely.